# matplotlib summary plot per record

Tags: matplotlib, summary, arcpy

I need to create a summary plot of a single parameter for each record in my database. Using the code below, I have managed to create a subplot for each record (5 in test database, ArcGIS 10.0 file geodatabase, Python 2.6.5, Matplotlib 1.0.0), but each subplot is identical. I have searched through the forum examples of summary plots/reports, subplot syntax, and looping techniques in my attempt to identify the proper syntax. I expect that my issue is an improper loop syntax, since I am plotting all records per plot instead of the desired one record per plot. After I resolve this basic plotting issues, I plan to expand the scope of my code to include 10-15 parameters per plot, 3-4 plots total, and some general summary information, all on a single page pdf per record. I am working with a few thousand records in total.

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. The forum has been an extremely helpful resource to me on numerous occasions over the past year. I am new to python and brand-new to using matplotlib, but I see the enormous potential of the language and this library. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

```
import arcpy
import os
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Variables
FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #feature class
P1_fld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #score field to chart
P2_fld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #score field to chart
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
nsubp = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(FC).getOutput(0)) #pulls n subplots from FC
last_val = object()

#Sub-plot loop
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(FC, "", "", P1_fld)
for row in cur:
    x=1
    y=row.getValue(P1_fld)
    if row.OBJECTID != last_val:
        for i,v in enumerate(xrange(nsubp)):
            v = v+1
            i = i+1
            ax = plt.subplot(nsubp,1,v) # Create a subplot.
            ax.scatter(x,y,s=5,color='blue'); # Generate the Scatter Plot.
            oid = str(row.getValue('OBJECTID'))
            figPDf = r"filepath.pdf" # Save the Scatter Plot to PDF.
            plt.savefig(figPDf)
del row, cur
os.startfile("filepath.pdf")
```

Comment: Combining for i,v in enumerate(xrange(nsubp)): with v=v+1 and i=i+1 seems like trouble

Comment: This happens because you are using a double `for` loop: you are plotting all the parameters for every iteration (i.e. for every subplot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have two nested `for` loops: the first loop iterates over each `row`, whereas the second loop makes the scatter plot appear on *every* subplot. This in turn means that every plotted parameter will appear on every subplot. To avoid this, you should avoid the double `for` loop.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve, but this should at least get you on your way.

```
import arcpy
import os
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Variables
FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #feature class
P1_fld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #score field to chart
P2_fld = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #score field to chart
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
nsubp = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(FC).getOutput(0)) #pulls n subplots from FC
last_val = object()

#Sub-plot loop
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(FC, "", "", P1_fld)
i = 0
x = 1
for row in cur:
    y = row.getValue(P1_fld)
    if row.OBJECTID != last_val:
        i += 1
        ax = plt.subplot(nsubp, 1, i) # Create a subplot.
        ax.scatter(x, y, s=5, color='blue'); # Generate the Scatter Plot.
        oid = str(row.getValue('OBJECTID'))
        figPDf = r"filepath.pdf" # Save the Scatter Plot to PDF.
        plt.savefig(figPDf)
del row, cur
os.startfile("filepath.pdf")
```

Comment: You are exactly right. My double for loops were causing the problem. When I removed the second for loop and incorporated your edits, the 5 plots only showed a single record's value. To get each record value to plot on its own, I also needed to remove the 'if row.OBJECTID' statement and dedent everything below. The script now gives me a unique plot for each record, which is what I needed. Many thanks, nordev!